# Comments filters and dummy email in custom post types in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email, custom-post-type

i want the people in my wordpress site to comment without entering an email address, i achieved this by applying a filter in my functions.php assigning a dummy email adress to the mail field.

```
 function comments_arguments_text($fields) {  
 $fields['email'] = '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">mail</label> 
                         <input id="email" name="email" type="text"  placeholder="mail@mail.com" value="mail@mail.com" size="30"/>
                         </p>';
  return $fields;
}

add_filter('comment_form_defaults', 'comments_arguments_text');
```

and hidden the < p > in css with the dummy email.
it works perfectly in regular posts, but it doesn't work in custom post types...
how can i make the filter apply to custom post types?

im spitting the comments in the single-custom-posttype.php using

```
   comments_template( '', true );
```

and im getting all the modifications i made with the filter (change the text of the submit button, etc) , only i dont get the mail field value....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that it is not only limited to custom post types, i was having the problem on regular posts too, here is how i solved the problem:

i changed :

```
add_filter('comment_form_defaults', 'comments_arguments_text');
```

to

```
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'comments_arguments_text');
```

and it works like magic ;)